# Lost select value after submitting and clicking on link

Tags: php, html, post

Hello I have problem that I'm loosing `$_POST['id']` value from select tag after clicking on href. Well the code is here:

```
$page = 1;
if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}

echo $id[0];
?>

<ul>
    <li><a href="?show=all">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=submitted">Show Submitted</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=pending">Show Pending</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=not">Show Not Submitted</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="id">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
        <option value="5">five</option>
        <option value="6">six</option>
        <option value="7">seven</option>
        <option value="8">eight</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="mode" value="Select" />
</form>
```

The idea is that after when i've selected some value from selected field I need to keep that value in variable and also I need for further filtering SQL query which works after `<a href="">`.
At the moment after submitting form I get select value, but after further filtering pressing any of `<a href="">` links `$_POST` value dissapears... how can I keep that value after pressing on any link?

Comment: Think for using GET not POST data ... 
You can set up all next links to posses your GET param id

Comment: clicking a link causes a GET request. you cannot get a POST without using a form or some javascript to catch the clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link click always produce GET request and does not submit a form by default. So you must pass it as a query parameter:

```
    <li><a href="?show=all<?=isset($id) ? '&id=' . $id : '' ?>">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=submitted<?=isset($id) ? '&id=' . $id : '' ?>">Show Submitted</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=pending<?=isset($id) ? '&id=' . $id : '' ?>">Show Pending</a></li>
    <li><a href="?show=not<?=isset($id) ? '&id=' . $id : '' ?>">Show Not Submitted</a></li>
```

And, of course, you will need to take it from `$_GET` in such case. But as you can get it from both `$_POST` and `$_GET` you may use `$_REQUEST` here:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
```

Comment: ohh thanks it works.. wondering that i've already used $_GET technique on other things but didnt thinked how to use it here.. My head not working on end of working day. Thanks alot mate! it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

By saving it somewhere. You have these options, for example

- Store it as query param on all the urls (listed in the other answer)
- Store it into a [cookie](http://php.net/cookies)
- Store it on the [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

And if it needs to be stored for a longer periods of time

- Store it on [DB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

If you only need it once, query param should be ok. If for several clicks/pageflows, somewhere more lasting would be appropriate.

Comment: Agree on cookie and session, but DB? When OP have no idea how to pass and id using link?

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't recommend it either at this point... But if it really needs to be *stored*, it would be the way to go, so it should be mentioned anyway.